# Extend RadPageView using ascx

Tags: telerik, ascx, rad-controls

I am using radmultipage. I want to extend radpageview using ascx. So I want to add myRadPageview to radmultipage at runtime. At runtime I can add myRadPageview to radmultipage like that

```
        deneme = new Page1();
        deneme.ID = "123";
        RadMultiPage1.PageViews.Add(deneme);
        RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

After that I add myRadPageview to radmultipage but controls in myRadPageview doesn't exist when I clicked view source in my browser

```
< div id="RadMultiPage1">

                </div><div id="123">

                </div><input id="RadMultiPage1_ClientState" name="RadMultiPage1_ClientState" type="hidden" />
            </div>
```

page1.ascx.cs

```
public partial class Page1 : Telerik.Web.UI.RadPageView
    {

        public Page1()
        {
            int i = 5;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

page1.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.ascx.cs" Inherits="Organon.IM.Presentation.ModellingModule.Page1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

<telerik:RadPageView ID="rpv1" runat="server" Height="159px" Width="163px">

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button32432"/>

</telerik:RadPageView>
```

Why controls which in page1 doesn't show in radmultipage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution. At runtime I can add myRadPageview to radmultipage like that

```
Telerik.Web.UI.RadPageView dataSelectionPV = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadPageView();
dataSelectionPV.ID = "dataSelectionPV";
System.Web.UI.Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("DevelopmentSample.ascx");
dataSelectionPV.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

developmentSample.ascx

```
public partial class DevelopmentSample : System.Web.UI.UserControl
...
```

also I deleted `<telerik:RadPageView ID="rpv1" runat="server" Height="159px" Width="163px">` tags from .ascx.cs

my new .ascx.cs file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.ascx.cs" Inherits="Organon.IM.Presentation.ModellingModule.Page1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button32432"/>
```